# How to use old schema of weaviate in haystack?

Tags: weaviate, haystack

I want to use weaviate as a database for haystack
using:

```py
from haystack.document_store import WeaviateDocumentStore
document_store = WeaviateDocumentStore(port= "", host="", username="", password="", index="document")
```

But each time it creates a new class. How can I connect to an already available class/schema?
Also `write_documents` is does not work..

```py
document_store.write_documents([docs])
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of haystack do you use?